# i hava an error creating a draggable component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, draggable

Hi i am triying to make a draggable component using a custom hook in react but i got this problem
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

here is the code for the custom hook

```js
import { useState } from "react";
const useDragable = dragItem => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [currentX, setCurrentX] = useState(0);
  const [currentY, setCurrentY] = useState(0);
  const [initialX, setInitialX] = useState(0);
  const [initialY, setInitialY] = useState(0);
  const [xOffset, setXoffset] = useState(0);
  const [yOffset, setYoffset] = useState(0);

  const dragStart = e => {
    console.log("dragItem");
    console.log(dragItem);
    e.target.classList.add("dragging");
    setInitialX(e.clientX - xOffset);
    setInitialY(e.clientY - yOffset);
    setActive(true);
  };
  const dragEnd = e => {
    e.target.classList.remove("dragging");
    setInitialX(currentX);
    setInitialY(currentY);
    setActive(false);
  };

  const drag = e => {
    if (active) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setCurrentX(e.clientX - initialX);
      setCurrentY(e.clientY - initialY);
      setXoffset(currentX);
      setYoffset(currentY);
    }

    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem.current);
  };
  function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
    if (el) {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }
  }
  return [dragStart, dragEnd, drag];
};

export default useDragable;
```

Here is for the component

```js
import React from "react";
import useDragable from "../../Custom/useDragable";
import { useRef } from "react";
const DragableFather = () => {
  const dragIm = useRef(null);
  const hookValue = useDragable(dragIm.current);
  const [dragStart, dragEnd, drag] = hookValue;

  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "lightblue", height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
      onDragOver={drag}
    >
      <div
        draggable="true"
        className="square"
        ref={dragIm}
        onClick={() => console.log(dragIm.current)}
        onDragStart={dragStart}
        onDragEnd={dragEnd}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default DragableFather;
```

Indeed its look like the ref created is not beign pased the right way.
and when i pass as an argument inside the component.

React throws an error of infinite renders

Comment: Considering these are pictures its hard to debug exactly whats going on, educated guess would be that somewhere you're trying to access `dragIm` before it's been fully initialized. Easiest might be to simply add error handling and check for null/ undefined values before accessing `dragIm`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but

1. in **setTranslate** add condition

```js
if (el) {
// your code
}
```

This will prevent the error but I don't think that will solve it

2. Try to pass to **useDraggable** only **dragIm** no **dragIm.current** and in your **useDraggable** pass to **setTranslate** as third argument **dragItem.current** instead of **dragItem**

Comment: i did what you write, now it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null", i think i have a proble with the ref, Thanks for the comment

Answer (score -1):

I find the problem!

When you use useRef you dont have to put a "this" before.

Thats why it give a bug, the second time i tried to change, i put a this in "ref={dragIm}"